# Why doesn't "is not None" work with dataframe.loc, but "!= None" works fine?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently playing with Pandas dataframe, I wanted to select all data entries in the dataframe which has not None entity attribute.

```py
df_ = df.loc[df['entities'] != None]
```

seems work pretty well
but

```py
df_ = df.loc[df['entities'] is not None]
```

will raise KeyError
which is

> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in >pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>    File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 128, in >pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>    File "pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in >pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
>   KeyError: True

Well I already know the solution to my original problem, I'm just curious why this happens

Comment: `df['entities'] is not None` is comparing the entire series with `None`, yielding `True` where as `df['entities'] != None` is an element-wise comparison, yielding boolean masking of series. Your second line is basically doing `df.loc[True]`, and unless you have a row index `True` (not `str` but `bool`) it is bound to a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of

```
df_ = df.loc[df['entities'] is not None]
```

or

```
df_ = df.loc[df['entities'] != None]
```

you should rather use

```
df_ = df.loc[df['entities'].notna()]
```

Because the representation of missing values in pandas is different from the usual python way to represent missing values by None. In particular you get the key error, because the column series `df['entities']` is checked for identity with `None`. This evaluates to `True` in any case, because the series is not `None`. Then the `.loc` searches the row index for `True`, which is not present in your case, so it raises the exception. `!=` doesn't cause this exception to be raised, because the equality operator is overloaded by `pandas.Series` (otherwise you couldn't build indexers by comparing a column with a fixed value like in `df['name'] == 'Miller'`). This overloaded method performs an elementwise comparison and itself returns an indexer that works fine with the `.loc` method. Just the result might not be, what you intended.

E.g. if you do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3], y=list('abc'), nulls= [None, np.NaN, np.float32('inf')]))

df['nulls'].isna()
```

It returns:

```
Out[18]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: nulls, dtype: bool
```

but the code:

```
df['nulls'] == None
```

returns

```
Out[20]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: nulls, dtype: bool
```

If you look at the datatype of the objects stored in the column, you see they are all floats:

```
df['nulls'].map(type)
Out[19]: 
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
Name: nulls, dtype: object
```

For columns of other types the representation of missing values might even be different. E.g. if you use `Int64` columns it looks like this:

```
df['nulls_int64']= pd.Series([None, 1 , 2], dtype='Int64')
df['nulls_int64'].map(type)
Out[26]: 
0    <class 'float'>
1      <class 'int'>
2      <class 'int'>
Name: nulls_int64, dtype: object
```

So using `notna()` instead of `!= None` also helps you to keep your code clean from handling pandas-internal data representations.

Comment: `notna()` is the opposite of `isna()`

Comment: Yes you're of course right @fc9.30. That slipped on me.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>I'm somewhat going out on a limb here, since I don't have experience with Pandas, but with Python…</sub>

Panda's magic filtering through `[]` is based a lot on operator overloading. In this expression:

```
df.loc[df['entities'] != None]
```

`df['entities']` is an object which implements the [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) method. Which means you're essentially doing:

```
df.loc[df['entities'].__ne__(None)]
```

The `df['entities'].__ne__(None)` is producing some new magic conditions object. The `df.loc` object implements the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method to overload the `[]` subscript syntax, so the whole thing is essentially:

```
df.loc.__getitem__(df['entities'].__ne__(None))
```

On the other hand, the [`is` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) is not overloadable. There's no `__is__` method an object could implement, so `df['entities'] is not None` is evaluated just as is by Python's core rules, and since `df['entities']` probably really is not `None`, the result of that expression is `True`. So just:

```
df.loc.__getitem__(True)
```

And that's why the error message complains about the `KeyError: True`.