# How to access iterating variables of generator comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

How to implement the following function `foo`

```py
foo(2*i for i in [1, 3, 5])  # returning something like [(1, 2), (3, 6), (5, 10)]
```

I didn't know it is possible before I see the [document](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html#:%7E:text=if%20x%20is%20a%20list,i%20in%20range(4)%2C) of a third-party module.

The `x` in the above link is just a special `dict` called `tupledict`. The following case is also legal.

```
model.addConstrs(i >= 0 for i in [4,3,2,0])
Out[32]: 
{4: <gurobi.Constr *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 3: <gurobi.Constr *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 2: <gurobi.Constr *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 0: <gurobi.Constr *Awaiting Model Update*>}
```

Comment: It's not possible. The generator just returns the results, it's not possible to determine how it calculated them.

Comment: what is the question ? How to write the `foo` method ? How to build the list you show in comment ?

Comment: @azro He wants the `foo()` function to somehow get the `x` values so it can combine them with the generated values.

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand how gurobi did it

Comment: The example you link to works very differently. In the example, `x` would be a special object which implements a lot of magic `__dunder__` methods for specific operators. It cannot work when `x` is just a plain integer.

Comment: It says it right there on the page: **if x is a Gurobi variable** It doesn't work with ordinary variables.

Comment: @deceze The `x` in my example are like the indexes like `i` and `j` in my link. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Well, no, they're not. The example is `x[i] for i in ...`. Very different from `2*x for x in ...`.

Comment: I've taken a stab at explaining this sort of magic syntax before, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670870/476.

Comment: @deceze please check the updated description.

Comment: Does `i >= 0 for i in [4,3,2,0]` *really* do what you think it does? I don't see this in the documentation. I'd think it's probably equivalent to `model.addConstrs([True, True, True, True])`…?!

Comment: @deceze This method only accept generators. Feeding list causes `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'gi_frame'`. And you can see the index values in the return dict.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def foo(g):
    res = []
    for val in g:
        indexes = [v for k, v in g.gi_frame.f_locals.items() if k != '.0']

        res.append(indexes+[val])
    return res
```

Something like that.

`gi_frame` and `f_locals` are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) so they are safe to use maybe.